# How can I make PhoneGap run with express using the same port in PhoneGap desktop application?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cordova, express

I am facing a problem connecting to a PhoneGap desktop application in my iPad.

I am using express to query to a MongoDB database which uses port 3000. However, PhoneGap desktop application also uses port 3000. If I change the port of my PhoneGap desktop application, I would be able to connect to the PhoneGap desktop application in my iPad. But, the query to MongoDB will not work.

How do I run both at the same time (being able to use in iPad)?

App.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/view');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(express.bodyParser()) ;
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

I tried using this method, the result is still the same.

```
var phonegap = require('connect-phonegap'),
express = require('express'),
app = express();

app.use(phonegap());
app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

please try the following code piece:

```
var server = app.listen(3000,'::1', function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('running at http://' + host + ':' + port)
});
```

And try accessing the node process using the following URL:

http://[::1]:3000/

Phonegap should be accessible on the following URL:

http://localhost:3000

Let me know if this helps.